# Define a class drop_first that has only two methods __init__ and __iter__

Tags: python

I am learning python these days and have a small question as follows:

Define a class drop_first that has only two methods **init** and **iter**

The constructor of drop_first has parameter iterable, to which an iterable is given.

Method **init** applies function iter to iterable and records the resulting iterator in some attribute. It then calls function next on the iterator once.

Method **iter** simply returns the iterator recorded in the attribute.

For example, the instance created by drop_first([1,2,3]) allows iteration skipping the first element 1.

for x in drop_first([1,2,3]): print(x)
2 and 3 will be printed.

I answered with the following codes:

```
class drop_first:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.index = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
          result = self.iterable[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index += 1
        return result
```

Nevertheless, I found that it was required to create a class with only 2 methods inside, and am a little bit confused about the specifications of those two methods. So I am wondering if anyone could give me some explainations about the requirement of the class...Thank you.

Comment: The problem specification is really explicit. There's very little for you to fill in. You didn't do any of the things the problem spec told you to do, like call `iter` on the iterable, or call `next` once on the resulting iterator, or return that iterator in `__iter__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Define a class drop_first that has only two methods init and iter

Bad instruction. This class should be called `DropFirst`. But be it.

> The constructor of drop_first has parameter iterable, to which an iterable is given.

```
def __init__(self, iterable):
```

> Method init applies function iter to iterable and records the resulting iterator in some attribute. It then calls function next on the iterator once.

```
self.iterator = iter(iterable)
next(self.iterator)
```

> Method iter simply returns the iterator recorded in the attribute.

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self.iterator
```

This results in

```
class DropFirst: # or, if your instructor insists on it, drop_first
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        next(self.iterator)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterator
```

But, to be honest, I'd take the following approach (which breaks the specifications, but is more versatile):

```
class DropFirst:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
    def __iter__(self):
        iterator = iter(self.iterable)
        next(iterator)
        return iterator
```

This works in all cases the original one also does, but can be iterated over several times.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation, it helped me with understanding the original question which, I think, is a little bit confusing for newbies... But I got one more question, why the second version with iterator and next in the iter method can be iterated over several times..? What is the difference between these two versions?

Comment: @hclin The difference is that an iterator is an object which can only be used once. Once it is exhausted, it's useless. An iterable like a list, string or whatever produces a new iterator on every call to `__iter__()`.